# How to hide Blue line covering views in xib/Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

[image]
I am using xcode 7.2, in xib when i insert  any view, label,txtField etc., all are showing this covering blue line. now it is very hard to insert/manage new view or anything in xib due to this line.
Does anybody know how to hide these?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. In Xcode: Editor > canvas > show bounds rectangles. This option show/hide the blue lines.

If you found this one not work first time, try twice toggling the show bounds rectangles option. Some time this is not work in first time.

Comment: In case you skipped the second paragraph, it's important! Try twice! Really funny detail to need to include, but happened to me.

Comment: Thanks to both of you Paola and Dave

Answer (score 30):

**For  Xcode 14 and Xcode 13 and Xcode 12**, repeat this step 3 times.  `XCode: Editor > canvas > Bounds rectangles`.

**For Xcode 11 and Xcode 10,** repeat this step 3 times.  `XCode: Editor > canvas > show Bounds rectangles`. This is a bug in Xcode 11 Xcode 10.

Comment: THIS IS A BUG IN XCODE 10 & 11. You're a life saver. What kind of bug is this?

Comment: Mostly this comes when you switch lower version to higher version of XCode. And use both versions at the same time.

Comment: Xcode is a bug in itself.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Got to Xcode and refer screenshot

Answer (score 3):

I have followed @Paola 's answer. but did not work for me .In addition I enabled and disabled it again than it removed blue lines. (Xcode Version 9.4)

Answer (score 1):

If none of the answers above did not work, try restarting your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select another device in storyboard (iPhone lower than 10 works for me) and reload Xcode
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQggJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 14. It could be either: Editor > Canvas > Layout Rectangles or Bounds Rectangles. Uncheck both.