# Xcode: What is this blue selection line and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Please refer to these two pics. There's this blue line next to the line number in my code. Hovering over it selects the code. I am not sure how it got there and how to get rid of it.

[image]

[image]

Clicking that line shows this:

[image]

EDIT: for whoever closed this question as "general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow": this is not that. Plus there are several Xcode UI questions on Stack Overflow:

For example:

[How to hide Blue line covering views in xib/Storyboard in Xcode 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553526/how-to-hide-blue-line-covering-views-in-xib-storyboard-in-xcode-7-2)

[How to get rid of blue borders around transparent objects in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813966/how-to-get-rid-of-blue-borders-around-transparent-objects-in-xcode/30814047)

Comment: This is the code that has been changed since the last commit to your source repo (ie Git repository).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this (last checkbox shown in this screen shot of the prefs):

[image]

You can uncheck it, but I advise not to; it's valuable information.

Comment: Thank you. I don't remember ever enabling source control so not sure how it got enabled. Disabling that last checkbox got rid of it. Thank you.

Comment: When you created you project Xcode gave you a git repository. You should use it, not ignore it.